# Folland Exercise 9.21b

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

> On $\mathbb{R}$, let $F$ be the constant function $1, G = \frac{d\delta}{dx}$, and $H = \chi_{(0,\infty)}$. Then $(F*G)*H$ and $F*(G*H)$ are well defined in $S'$ but are unequal.

Without doing anything formal, I can intuitively see that:

$G*H = \delta'* \chi_{(0,\infty)} = (\delta * \chi_{(0,\infty)})' = \chi_{(0,\infty)}' = \delta$

and that:

$F*G = (1*\delta') = (1*\delta)' = <1,\delta>' = \left( \int_\mathbb{R} \delta \right)' = 1' = 0$

However, that's intuition and I'm not really using the theory of distributions which I'm struggling with. For example, how do I use the fact that for $F \in D'(U)$ and $\psi \in C_c^\infty(U)$  that $(F*\psi)(x) = <F, \tau_x\tilde{\psi}>$ to show the above (here, $\tau$ is the translation operator and $\psi(-x) = \tilde{\psi}(x)$. In other words, I understand how to intuitively see what the answer should be, but not how to use distribution theory to formally prove it.

Comment: Convolution of distributions is not always well defined, so you've to look for some definition. You may try smoothing the distributions or for $F$, take a function $\phi$ equal to 1 near the origin, and investigate $\phi(\epsilon x)$ for $\epsilon\to 0$. Particularly, I like definitions using Fourier transform, e.g. $F*G:=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\hat{F}\hat{G})$ ($\mathcal{F}$ is Fourier transform), and you see that $\hat{F}=\delta$, $\hat{G}=x$, so $F*G=0$.

Comment: @user39490 Two questions about your comment if I can ask: (a) Why is $\hat{G} =0?$ And (b) how do you get $F*G =0$? I see $F*G = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \xi \delta(\xi)e^{2\pi i \xi x} d\xi$, so how do you conclude that it is $0$?

Comment: Brenton, I didn't write $\hat{G}=0$, but $\hat{G}(x)=x$. The product of $\delta$ and a continuous function $f$ is well defined, you can define it as $\delta f = f(0)$, or in distributional language $\langle \delta f,\phi\rangle=(f\phi)(0)$; hence $\delta x = 0$. To see $\hat{G}=x$, by definition $\langle \delta',\hat{\phi}\rangle=-\hat{\phi}'(0)=\int x\phi(x)\,dx$. Good luck and you can always ask!

Comment: @user39490 Yea I meant $x$, not $0$. Not sure what I was thinking. I think I'm having a difficult time understanding the notation of $<\delta f, \phi> = (f\phi)(0)$. For example, I can understand $\delta(f) = f(0)$ as delta being a functional, but I get confused on the notation when we include a test function and how to go back and forth between the notation with the test function and the notation of using a functional

Comment: I think Folland should give you some kind of rule of "good" definition or some guidance, because anyone can define things in any way, but the problem is the consistency of your definition. If you want to see how a distribution works, you can smooth and manipulate it as a usual function. Finally, I give you a simple example: let $F$ be a distribution and $G$ a $C^{\infty}$ function slowly increasing, you can say that $FG$ is the distribution $(FG,\phi):=(F,G\phi)$, because $G\phi\in\mathcal{S}$.